# Provide image to Javascript from Java library

Tags: javascript, java

I have some kind of image viewer java application that basically draws images generated by a third-party java library. This library serves me java.awt.Image objects dynamically, I mean that the image gets updated by some user actions, scroll zooming for example, and it's pretty fast.

Now I would like to display those images in a website using Javascript that is supposed to react to user interaction too. What would be an efficient way to serve those images from the java library to make them available for Javascript?

Is there any option besides saving an image file from the java library everytime there's a request from the website for a new image?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The api returns the image data, no need to save the image to a file.

Comment: What format is the image data in? If it's a blob, you can use URL.createObjectURL(blob)in JavaScript to turn it into a URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Java HTTP Server. Then you can send a http request from your javascript to your Java API and the response could be the image.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I have already an http server running so I can use it for that, thank you so much!